# VBA Replace not working with numbers format

Tags: string, vba, replace, phone-number

I am, once again, stuck on something.

I am trying to clean phone numbers data, and the code isn't doing anything.

```
    Columns(icount).Replace What:=",", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False


    Columns(icount).Replace What:="-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

icount is the column where the phone # are.

I don't understand why it's not working. Replacing "`&agrave;`" with "à" works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using 'LookAt:=xlPart' instead of using 'LookAt:=xlWhole'

```
Columns(icount).Replace What:=",", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False


Columns(icount).Replace What:="-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
```

Answer (score 1):

You could it like so:

```
Sub rep()


For Each c In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Cells ' Change the range that you want

    If InStr(c.Value, ",") > 0 Then
        deli = Split(c, "")
        For a = 0 To UBound(deli)
        c.Value = replace(c.Value, ",", "")
        Next a

    End If

    If InStr(c.Value, "-") > 0 Then
        deli = Split(c, "")
        For a = 0 To UBound(deli)
        c.Value = replace(c.Value, "-", "")
        Next a

    End If

Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, this does exactly what I want. But I don't understand it really.